# Timeit Python. How does it work?

Tags: python, syntax, timer, timeit

I want to time a function and I'd like to use the timeit library. I can't find any good example on the net. I have to time the function "largest_eigenvector" which is in the maxcut library, this function takes as input a graph G wich is returned by a function in the networkx library.

So I want to time this block of code:

```
import maxcut as mc 
import networkx as nx 
G = nx.complete_graph(3)

mc.largest_eigenvector(G)
```

It obviously works fine. Than to time it I did this:

```
s = """
    import maxcut as mc 
    import networkx as nx 
    G = nx.complete_graph(3)
    """
t = timeit.Timer(s, 'mc.largest_eigenvector(G)')
```

But it says:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mc' referenced before assignment

I don't know why. Please someone help it's just a syntax problem and I can't find a decent documentation for this.

Answer (score 4):

You have statement and setup swapped. Pass the arguments to Timer() the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def tmp():
    import maxcut as mc 
    import networkx as nx 
    G = nx.complete_graph(3)
    mc.largest_eigenvector(G)

t = timeit.Timer(s, 'tmp()')
```

The following might work, too:

```
t = timeit.Timer(setup=s, stmt='mc.largest_eigenvector(G)')
```

Comment: It works fine your solution thanks..:) But is there a more elegant way to do this?